# Как узнать размеры активити-контейнера для фрагмента?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Итак, есть Activity, в которой находятся несколько фрагментов. В какой-то момент нужно изменить размеры фрагментов — один растянуть на весь экран, второй уменьшить до нуля. Разметка примерно такая (убрал ненужные подробности в виде кнопок и проч.):

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/timer_main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock_rewersed">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_below_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock_rewersed">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Нашёл способ изменить высоту фрагментов следующим образом:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //наследуется от View
    drawView = new DrawView(getActivity());

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    //задаём высоту за вычетом нижнего меню
    drawView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(displayMetrics.widthPixels,
            displayMetrics.heightPixels - (int) (50 / displayMetrics.density)));
    Log.d("onCreateView", "exit");
    return drawView;
}
```

Во втором фрагменте убираю высоту по тому же сценарию:

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_below_timer, container, false);
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(displayMetrics.widthPixels, 1));
    return view;
}
```

Так вот первый фрагмент растягивается, но второй не убирается и перекрывает его.

UPD. Решение задачи — следующее. Перед созданием фрагмента создаём экземпляр `FrameLayout` и меняем его свойства (в `Activity`-родителе):

```
case R.id.account:
                setUnderlineAlpha(accountUnderline);
                headingText.setText("Данные пользователя");

                Fragment fragment = FragmentAccount.newInstance();
                viewGroup.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(displayMetrics.widthPixels,
                        (int) (displayMetrics.heightPixels - (123 * displayMetrics.density))));
                showFragmentTop(fragment);

                showFragmentBottom(FragmentBelowAccount.newInstance());
                break;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, проблема в том, что у второго фрагмента `match_parent`. Это означает, что высота фрагмента будет вычисляться позже. Попробуйте обернуть строку изменения высоты в Global Layout Listener:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(displayMetrics.widthPixels, 1));
    }
});
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не решило проблему. Фрагменты меняют свои размеры, но не заходят за рамки, определённые при создании.

Comment: А, я понял. Объект `view` - это то, что инфлейтится для фрагмента и располагается ВНУТРИ ваших `FrameLayout`. Попробуйте управлять размерами контейнеров из активити.

Comment: Хорошая идея. Сейчас попробую. Но как это сделать?

Comment: Ну в активити у Вас есть ссылки на два `FrameLayout`. Они такие же наследники `View`. Меняйте их размеры просто и все.

Comment: Да, наконец-то всё заработало. Спасибо.